# Automatically select Instagram in UIDocumentInteractionController or UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, uiactivityviewcontroller, uidocumentinteraction

UIDocumentInteractionController and UIActivityViewController both present menus for sharing images out to other networks. After hitting Instagram, you are presented with a nice modal that allows you to post to Instgram without leaving the app. My question is, how do I automatically show that modal without showing the menu?

This app called Sounds does it so I know it's possible, but I can't find any documentation online about how it's done. Here is the current code I have which shows the menu:

```
    NSString *documentDirectory=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *saveImagePath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.ig"];
    NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(cardImage);
    [imageData writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveImagePath];

    UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageURL];
    docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:imageURL usingDelegate:self];
    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(1, 1, 1, 1) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Here's the menu: 
[image: 1]

Here's what I want to automatically show:

[image: 2]]

Comment: Did you find any solution to the problem? I am with same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're able to use UIActivityViewController to show up Instagram as long there is just an UIImage inside the activity items.
It won't show up if you add more items like text, url etc.
This is a bad limitation made by Instagram.

Like so:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
[items addObject:[UIImage ...]];

// show view
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items
                                                                             applicationActivities:nil];
[vc presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

The code I used to share image on instagram

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class SocialShare: NSObject {
    static let shared = SocialShare()

    func postImageToInstagram(image: UIImage) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(SocialShare.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }
    func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: fetchOptions)
        if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
            let localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
            let u = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + localIdentifier
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: u)!)
        }
    }
}
```

No anywhere you want to use just call

```
SocialShare.shared.postImageToInstagram(UIImage(named: "1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Swift 4 class that implements Zuhair's answer.

```
import Foundation
import Photos

class InstagramSharer: NSObject {
    static let shared = InstagramSharer()

    func post(image: UIImage) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }

    @objc
    private func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

        if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject {
            let localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
            let url = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + localIdentifier
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: url)!)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
InstagramSharer.shared.post(image: #YOUR_IMAGE#)
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the other applications from being displayed change following lines of code (Just flip them):

```
docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:imageURL usingDelegate:self];
```

So that the .UTI variable is set after overriding the docController object.

EDIT: If you are attempting to directly open the Instagram application with the information filled out and ready to share check out the iPhone hooks [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/).

Comment: I know it's a really specific request, but the iPhone hooks isn't really what we're looking for. We don't want to leave the app, we just want to pull up that modal automatically. This app Sounds (https://www.sounds.am/) does it. You click an Instagram button and it brings up that modal immediately. Any idea how that is done?

Comment: This is exactly what I've been Googling for the last 2 days. Have you found an answer? I've seen apps do this so I know it's possible.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this? Because I am seeing some apps use the exact feature you described but no amount of googling helped me find the solution @evenodd